# Unarchiver Sprite Kit's Physics joints

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I'm writing a small game for iPad based on SpriteKit.

I have a kind of bottles that contains bubbles and a special container that holds nodes linked to the bubbles with SKPhysicsJointSpring.

Then I'm trying to save and restore entire scene using

> [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self]

and

> [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive]

After unarchiving is complete, at first bubbles appear at the right places,
but then they move to some strange positions, as if dragged by SKPhysicsJointSpring.

Holders and other nodes are all in the right positions.

Am I doing the saving/restoring thing with SKPhysicsJoints correctly?